# Iterating over IEnumerable in view does not print anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to print out multiple images using a `foreach` loop in the `view` and passing in an `IEnumerable<Image>` through the model.

My problem is that the `foreach` loop doesn't display the images at all, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I've tried this about 16 different ways and I am still not getting anything other than a broken image link or nothing at all.

Will someone please take a look and see if they can figure out what I am doing wrong? It's probably something very simple and I'm just missing it.

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult UploadCommission(CommissionViewModel model)
{
    List<Image> fileNames = new List<Image>();

    //loop through multiple files
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in model.Files)
    {
        //get file names
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

        //save files
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + filename));
        string filepathtosave = "~/Content/" + filename;

        fileNames.Add(new Image()
        {
            FilePath = filepathtosave
        });
    }

    model.ImageFilePaths = fileNames;

    return RedirectToAction("ViewComm", model);
}
```

And here's my `View` that displayed the information:

```
@foreach (CapstoneProject.Models.Image i in Model.ImageFilePaths)
{
    <img src="@Url.Content(i.FilePath)" />
}

@Model.Title

@Model.Price

@Model.Limit

@foreach (string tag in Model.Tags)
{
    <p>@tag</p>
}

@Model.Description
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: When you say the "foreach loop doesn't display the images at all", do you mean that the `img` tags aren't in the source at all or that their `src` is broken?

Comment: Using only the code above, what is the value of any of those images src attribute?

Comment: @Jacob The image tags are not in the source with the current..  ErikPhilips Are you asking if there is actually a value to the images? Because I am passing a valid image object, but the src does not display anything as being there.

Comment: Why not just return the `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `RedirectToAction`; according to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action.

When you pass that model when redirecting to an action, that data will be lost through the redirection action. What you probably want to do instead is make sure you pass the image URLs in the redirect URL or not use a redirect at all (just render a view)

Comment: Yep, that was my problem. I got confused, because you can RedirectToAction when just passing one image, but not multiple it seems. Thanks so much for the fix!!

Answer (score 0):

There's really not enough to work with here to effectively answer your question, but there's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've provided. However, in order for any `Image` instances to be added to the list they must have been posted in the first place (i.e., if `model.Files` itself is empty, then so will be your `IEnumerable<Image>`.

To that end, there's two things you should check:

1. Ensure that your form has `accept="multipart/form-data"` on it. Otherwise, uploads will not be posted.
2. Ensure that your file upload field names are such that they'll bind to the model property on post. In your scenario here, they would need names like `Files[N]`, where `N` is the index.